# chrome RTCPeerConnection event not fire after connected

Tags: webrtc

I have several listener for peerConnection object, the onConnection is fired in firefox and works good, but not fired in Chrome, do you know why?

```
pc1.onconnection = handleOnconnection;
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = handleState;
pc1.onreadystatechange = handleState;
```

so does pc2.

thanks for any help!

Rosone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onconnection` is not part of the interface in the latest standard, so that's probably why it's not implemented in Chrome: http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#interface-definition.

The code in Firefox lists `onconnection` as a Mozilla extension: https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/master/dom/webidl/RTCPeerConnection.webidl#L98.

For more details, you may want to ask the Mozilla team on the [dev-media](https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-media) list.